# Scripy sparse matrix

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with millions of rows and I would like to keep all the data in scripy sparse matrices to prevent memory issues.

```
id     value     count
002    groupB      1
001    groupB      3
001    groupC      1
003    groupC      2
002    groupA      1
004    groupZ      1
 ...

df.groupby(['id', 'value'])['count'].sum()

id  value 
1   groupB    3
    groupC    1
2   groupA    1
    groupB    1
3   groupC    2
4   groupZ    1
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

I am trying to use the result from groupby sum into a sparse matrix. My predefined headers/columns name in the `columns_names` array. I looked up csc_matrix and csr_matrix but have no idea how to transfer the groupby result into sparse.

My end goal is to have a dataframe like this with predefined column names (not necessarily in alphabetical order):

```
id   groupA    groupB    groupC    groupD   groupE  ..  groupZ   groupAA    ...
001    0         3         1         0        0           0        0
002    1         1         0         0        0           0        0
003    0         0         2         0        0           0        0 
004    0         0         0         0        0           1        0
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In pandas 0.23, there is a [SparseSeries](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/sparse.html#sparseseries) data structure, you can use it to get a sparse matrix:

```
s = df.groupby(['id', 'value'])['count'].sum()

ss = s.to_sparse()  # convert to sparse series
coo, rows, columns = ss.to_coo(row_levels=['id'], column_levels=['value'], sort_labels=True)  # convert to coo
result = coo.tocsr()  # convert to csr

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
  (0, 1)    3
  (0, 2)    1
  (1, 0)    1
  (1, 1)    1
  (2, 2)    2
  (3, 3)    1
```

First you convert it to a sparse series, then to coo (see [to_coo](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.SparseSeries.to_coo.html#pandas.SparseSeries.to_coo)) and finally, if needed, to csr. The variable rows and columns contains the rows and columns labels from the multi-index. For the above example the column labels are:

```
['groupA', 'groupB', 'groupC', 'groupZ']
```

and the row labels are:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: is it possible to pass in my defined labels? I don't want to sort the labels because they are not alphabetical

Comment: You could set sort_labels to false `sort_labels=False`, see if that works.